force powershell terminal window to stay on top
There is a startup script that launches at system bootup. The script prints a countdown to allow user to opt-out of the default action.
The script is a simple posh terminal, no forms or other GUI elements are used:
[int]$t = 15
$len = $t / 100
For (; $t -gt 0; $t--) {
    $text = "" + $t + " seconds"
    Write-Progress -Activity "starting task in" -Status $text -PercentComplete ($t / $len)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

Start-Process some-task-to-execute

As the default action is to launch some-task-to-execute, it's important to keep this terminal window on top so user can see what's about to happen and allow easy opt-out access.
Been through plenty stackexchange and other forum posts regarding placing windows on top, but none seem to be working in windows 11 anymore. How to accomplish this?
Or am I better off rewriting this using forms, as there are (still) working ways to force forms on top? Or maybe rewriting this in AHK for the same reason?

I'd say, forms is the way to go here. That way, you can also ensure that the form is not intrusive to the user, so they don't mind having it always visible, whereas a script window may be bothersome to some users.

Does this help: https://www.howtogeek.com/196958/ways-to-make-a-window-always-on-top-on-windows/ ?

@LPChip cheers, think I'll just go with the frames then.

@DrMoishePippik nope, as it should be handled programmatically by script (or its launcher) itself.
